# How to select only the rows that have a column with a repeated value?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am building an Android app for a bus schedule between my village and Barcelona.

I have built a sqlite database as follows (probably it's a really bad design, but I'm a newbie in databases):

```
run | stopCode | time
1.........1.......620
1.........2.......650
.
.
.
5........11.......NULL
5........12.......1020
```

And so on.

I use the following SQL statement in order to pick the rows that match my criteria:

```
 SELECT run,stopCode,time
 FROM tablename
 WHERE time> x AND time <>'' AND (stopCode=1 or stopCode=8);
```

Using this sentence gives me an output similar to this:

```
6(run)|8(stopCode)|1045(time)
9|1|1900
9|8|2000
```

My problem is that I want to select **only** the rows that have the run value repeated twice. If it only appears once, it means that the bus has a NULL destination in that particular run.

I tried using `COUNT(*) c`, `blabla c=2`, but that gives me only the second row with the repeated run number, and I want to select both of them (which would correspond to where you pick the bus and where you want to go down). Any clues how to do it?

Edit:

this is the statement i tried

```
SELECT run,stopNumber,time,COUNT(run) c 
FROM Directes_dirBarna 
WHERE time> 600 and time<>'' and (stopNumber=1 or stopNumber=8) 
GROUP BY run having c=2;
```

Edit2:

Thanks to Marcos Vasconcelos i fixed it. This is my final statement if anyone has the same problem:

```
SELECT run,parada, hora FROM Directes_dirBarna taula WHERE hora> 600
and TIME<>'' IN (parada=1, parada=8);
```

Comment: group by `having` count >1

Comment: @DrewPierce i already did this (i think i did it well). This is the statement i tried:
sqlite> select run,stopNumber,time,COUNT(run) c from Directes_dirBarna where time> 600 and time<>'' and (stopNumber=1 or stopNumber=8) group by run having c=2;

Comment: @AleixSanchis: add your attempts in the question (by [edit]ing it), not in comments. (And try to format the SQL so that it's a bit readable.)

Comment: @mat try to clean up links and content

Comment: @DrewPierce: I'm sorry I don't get you.

Comment: @Mat i already edited the post, sorry 'bout that :)

Comment: @Mat you need formating advice. not major bro

Comment: @DrewPierce: please be more specific. There are no links in the post; and I edited the contents too. What did I miss?

Comment: @mat just post an answer i will upvote it i swear (if rational)

Comment: You can use the IN operator and repeat the query (but it would be bad if any other option is available)

Comment: @DrewPierce: If you have problem with my edits, either correct them or tell me what to fix. Or flag for a mod if you think they're egregiously bad. I have no idea where your last comment comes from.

Comment: I would do a join on the same table, like `select * from tablename as t1 tablename as t2 where t1.run = t2.run and t1.stopCode = 1 and t2.stopCode = 8`

Comment: do you have an Answer @Mat

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I just tried that and it works! Thanks a lot dude. I definetly need some sleep, i don't know why i didn't try it early. I love you man, now i can relax for the rest of the afternoon <3.

Comment: Nope, try upvoting my answer ;)

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos i don't know how, you didn't post an answer but a comment :(

Comment: I added it as an answer, and its the arrow up

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos i know how to upvote haha :D it looks like I don't have enough reputation yet, soz :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
select t1.run, t1.code, t2.code from tablename t1, tablename t2
    where t1.run = t2.run and t1.code = 1 and t2.code = 8;
```

You select 2 rows (t1 and t2) such as they are on the same run, one is the departure, and one is the arrival. It will give you a single line for each run that satisfies the condition.

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7d3f3/3

Comment: After i tested a while, i definetly love your answer since i have now the query organized in a single line. Thanks mate, you were really helpful <3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputations to add it as a comment. If I understand correctly what the question is, to select runs that are 5 or 8 and that should be more than once in the table with some constraints on time. 
For that the solution is

```
SELECT a.run, a.stopNumber,time 
FROM Directes_dirBarna a, Directes_dirBarna b 
WHERE a.run = b.run AND (a.run= 5 or a.run = 8) AND time> 600 and time<>'';
```

remove (a.run= 5 or a.run = 8) if you want any run that repeated twice.

Comment: the problem is that this returns a line for every stop that match either the origin or the destination. instead of one line for each run that goes from origin to destination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN operator and repeat the query (but it would be bad if any other option is available)